# php trader_ema(Exponential Moving Average in php) function leading zero's float

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to use the PHP [trader_ema function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trader-ema.php). However the input of a array with a leading zero's resultants in zero. Example:

```
realArray = array(0.0000002,0.000004,0.00005,0.00003);
var_dump(trader_ema ( $realArray, 2 )); 

//Output: 
array(5) { [1]=> float(0) [2]=> float(0) [3]=> float(0) [4]=> float(0) }
```

I think the problem is that PHP stores it's float into the array with scientific notation. But after searching I haven't found a solution yet. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe try with ints to see if its got a problem with floats, *scientific notation* as you say values are the same as the floats so it shouldn't be the problem, most likely the function expects ints (not seen anyone use the function with floats).

Comment: hmm, int wouldn't allow numbers like 0.00002 which are from my dataset. I have found a workaround which works for now butI still would like to use the trader_ema function.

workaround:

     $lastEMA5 = 0;
     $k = 2/(5+1);
for ($i=0; $i<count($resultset); ++$i) {
    $lastEMA5 = $lastEMA5 + $k * ($resultset[$i]-$lastEMA5);
}

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up this option:

```
ini_set('trader.real_precision', '8');
var_dump(trader_ema(array(0.0000002, 0.000004, 0.00005, 0.00003), 2 ));
```

output:

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  float(2.1E-6)
  [2]=>
  float(3.403E-5)
  [3]=>
  float(3.134E-5)
}
```